# How to call validate from external jquery file

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My jquery validation code is working as internal jquery code but i want to call this code in my page via external file i am doing i am unable to call

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=name.UniqueID %>:{
                        required:true
                    },
                    <%=password.UniqueID %>:{
                        required:true,
                         minlength:5,
                    },
                    <%=repassword.UniqueID %>:{
                        required:true,
                        equalTo:"#password"
                    },
                    <%=email.UniqueID %>: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                     <%=mobile.UniqueID %>: {

                        required:true,
                        digits:true,
                        minlength:10,
                        maxlength:10,

                      }

                }, 

                messages: {
                    <%=name.UniqueID %>:{
                        required: "* Required Field *"
                    },
                    <%=password.UniqueID %>:{
                        required:"* Required Field *"
                    }

                }




        });


});


    </script>
```

This is my jquery code which i am using as internal code it is working fine please help me to call this code from external js file. in my asp .net code that is-

> ```
>    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css"/> </head> <body  runat="server">
>  <form id="form1" runat="server" >    <div>
>
> <asp:label  ID="heading" runat="server" text="Validation  Form"></asp:label>    <table>    <tr>
>    <td class="deslabel">Name</td>
>    <td><asp:TextBox Id="name" CssClass="destext" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>    </tr>   <tr>
>    <td class="deslabel">Password</td>
>   <td> <asp:TextBox Id="password" CssClass="destext" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>    </tr>    <tr>
>    <td class="deslabel">Repassword</td>
>   <td> <asp:TextBox Id="repassword" CssClass="destext" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>    </tr>    <tr>
>    <td class="deslabel">E-Mail ID</td>
>    <td><asp:TextBox Id="email" CssClass="destext" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>    </tr>        
>      <tr >
>          <td class="deslabel">Mobile Number</td>
>       <td>  <asp:TextBox Id="mobile" CssClass="destext" class="groupName" runat="server" MaxLength="10" ></asp:TextBox></td>
>      </tr>
>       <tr >
>          <td class="deslabel">Gender</td>
>        <td>
>     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
>     <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="Male" />
>     <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="Female" />
>     </asp:RadioButtonList>
>     <p></p>
>     </td>
>      </tr>
>      <tr align="center">   
>        <td colspan="2">  <asp:Button ID="Button1"  CssClass="destext"          OnClientClick="value" runat="server" Text="submit"/></td> 
>
>          </tr>
>          </table>    </div>
>  </form> </body> </html>
> ```

Comment: have u included the js file in the html page ?i can't find it in the html

Comment: Yes, I included the Jscript.js file...

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the script tags, copy the code into for example `validate.aspx` - since you have ASP in the file, you need to execute them as asp code
2. add 
   `<script src="validate.apsx"></script>` in the head of the page along with 
   `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

the aspx will have to send the header to set the mime type :

```
<% response.ContentType="text/javascript" %>
 $(document).ready(function(){ ...
```

Alternative change ALL `<%=xxxx.UniqueID %>` to xxxx in the js where xxxx is the actual ID of the field and include it as .js instead

Last alternative is to have

```
<script>
var fieldNames = { 
  name:"<%=name.UniqueID %>",
  password:"<%=password.UniqueID %>",
  repassword: "<%=repassword.UniqueID %>",
  email:"<%=email.UniqueID %>",
  mobile:"<%=mobile.UniqueID %>"
}
</script>
```

in the ASP and have something like

```
 $("#form1").validate({
   rules: {
     fieldNames["name"] : {
       required:true
     },
```

in the JS file